# Activity destroyed by garbage collection and all fragments in backstack are showing instead of only current activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have enabled the setting to destroy actvities when you navigate away from an activity
Settings=>Developer Options=>Don't Keep activites

This should basically replicate an activity or fragment getting garbaged collected and then I have to restore the data via the bundle savedinstancestate.

So I understand how that works.  But it seems when I navigate from fragment 1 to fragment 2 and then put the application in the background and then in the foreground(destroying the activity)
Both fragment 1 and fragment 2 show at the same time.  In which only fragment 2 should be showing.

I do not know if this is something standard that I have to manage hiding and showing fragments onsavedinstance.  Or if something in my code is breaking things.  Below is how I push fragments which I hope is helpful:

```
public void pushFragmentWithAnimation(FragmentManager fm, int parentId, Fragment currentFrag, Fragment newFrag, int animEntry, int animExit) {
    hideSoftKeyboard(currentFrag.getActivity());
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    // See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations(int, int, int, int)
    ft.setCustomAnimations(animEntry, animExit, animEntry, animExit);
    ft.add(parentId, newFrag, String.format("Entry%d", fm.getBackStackEntryCount())).hide(currentFrag).show(newFrag);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Fragment 1 is still in the backstack because when I press back I only see fragment 1.  Let me know if you know why this is happening.

Comment: Can you add your onCreate() code (or what code you use to create fragment 1)?

Comment: Fragment 1 is added via xml of the activity.  Also another interesting fact is that if I navigate to fragment 3 and put the app in the background and then back in the foreground.  All 3 fragments show.  Fragment 2 and fragment 3 are added via the code in my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure why this solution works. I assume its related to if the activity gets killed that it does not keep track of which fragment is currently shown and shows all of the fragments. So basically I needed to replace:

```
ft.add(parentId, newFrag, String.format("Entry%d", fm.getBackStackEntryCount())).hide(currentFrag).show(newFrag);
```

with

```
ft.replace(parentId, newFrag, tag);
```

Then when I create the initial fragment in the main activity. I only would do that when

```
if(savedInstanceState==null){
```

My updated code is below: https://github.com/CorradoDev/FragmentTest/tree/2c53f9f42e835da768f61b0233f3ab5b3adf2448

Answer (score 1):

The lifecycle of XML added Fragments and programmatically added Fragments differ enough to make mixing them a bad idea, as explained in detail [here](http://portabledroid.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/programmatic-and-layout-fragments/).

The easiest way around this is to make all fragments programmatically added by replacing your XML inflated Fragment with a FrameLayout of the same ID, then in your onCreate add

```
FragmentManager fragMgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
if (null == fragMgr.findFragmentByTag(FRAG_TAG))
{
    fragMgr.beginTransaction().
        add(R.id.fragment, new Fragment1(), FRAG_TAG).commit();
}
```

Where `FRAG_TAG` is any unique string. This ensures that Fragment1 is only created if it is not already in the layout.

Comment: I do not think the xml fragment is the problem.  I created a test project you can pull down in which you can reproduce the exact problem I am having without the xml fragment
https://github.com/CorradoDev/FragmentTest

Comment: I found a solution.  I updated the question.  Thanks for your help with the fact that putting fragments in xml is a bad idea if you are also doing it in the code.